# Parsing data from Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, alamofire

Need to parse only the keys. **Here keys are (10, 12, 2, 26)**. All these keys are changeable. Also, need to parse the **fields** array. Not getting the data(keys -10, 12, 2, 26) and can not access the **fields** array.

```
{
    data =     {
        10 =         {
            fields =             (
                                {
                    text = Activity;
                    value = 0;
                },
                                {
                    text = Duration;
                    value = "0 hrs";
                },
                                {
                    text = Achievement;
                    value = "0 hrs";
                }
            );
            indicator = "+0%";
            "indicator_color" = "#0ebb39-";
            title = "Negotiation (Office)";
        };
        12 =         {
            fields =             (
                                {
                    text = Activity;
                    value = 0;
                },
                                {
                    text = Duration;
                    value = "0 hrs";
                },
                                {
                    text = Achievement;
                    value = "0 hrs";
                }
            );
            indicator = "+0%";
            "indicator_color" = "#0ebb39-";
            title = "Proposal Preparation";
        };
        2 =         {
            fields =             (
                                {
                    text = Activity;
                    value = 0;
                },
                                {
                    text = Duration;
                    value = "0 hrs";
                },
                                {
                    text = Achievement;
                    value = "0 hrs";
                }
            );
            indicator = "+0%";
            "indicator_color" = "#0ebb39-";
            title = "Departmental Work";
        };
        26 =         {
            fields =             (
                                {
                    text = Activity;
                    value = 0;
                },
                                {
                    text = Duration;
                    value = "0 hrs";
                },
                                {
                    text = Achievement;
                    value = "0 times";
                }
            );
            indicator = "+0%";
            "indicator_color" = "#0ebb39-";
            title = "External Meeting";
        };
            indicator = "+0%";
            "indicator_color" = "#0ebb39-";
            title = "Pre-sales (Office)";
        };
    };
    "error_code" = 0;
    message = "Dashboard Summary";
    status = success;
    success = 1;
}
```

Here is some of my code where I am trying to parse it using Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters,headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
                print(parameters)
                switch response.result{
                case.success(let data):
                    print("Success")
                    print(response)
                    //response.result.value
                    if let dataDict = data as? [String: Any] {
                        print("Here is my dataDict -\(dataDict)")
                        guard let rootData = dataDict["data"] as? [String: Any] else {return}   
                    }
                case .failure(let error)://let error
                    print("dddd",error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: What does `print(rootData)` show? And actually `rootData` is `dataDict` and vice versa

Comment: @vadian it's shows - 
"12": {
    fields =     (
                {
            text = Activity;
            value = 0;
        },
                {
            text = Duration;
            value = "0 hrs";
        },
                {
            text = Achievement;
            value = "0 hrs";
        }
    );

Comment: Great, that's correct, now enumerate the dictionary with `for (key, value) in rootData { ...`

Comment: @vadian I am getting the values in the key-value pattern but how could I store the keys and make another for loop inside the fields array. Thank you

Comment: It's straightforward. Get the value for key `fields` and cast it to a `[[String: Any]]` array. Then enumerate the array with another loop. Enumerating arrays and dictionaries is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @vadian Got it. Getting the values. Thanks